# Javascript not returning all attributes on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a weird problem. I’m using a java applet in my html page. This applet has a “read” function. 
My JS code is as follows:

```
var ap =  document.getElementById(“readingapplet”);
if(ap.read) {
  ap.start();
  ap.read();
}
```

On firefox, ap.read is a pointer to a function and works without issues. However in IE, ap.read is undefined.
Could this be an issue with IE’s Javascript engine?

===================
Update:

If I call the functions directly, they work as expected. The issue is in the attribute

Comment: If I call the functions directly, they work as expected. The issue is in the attribute

Comment: i wonder if it's because you're using `“` and `”` instead of `"`

Comment: @Brian in the code it is ""